# Why can't CakePhp see my stylesheets

Tags: php, cakephp

I am taking over a project from someone else that left. I'm currently trying to set up my environment. When I look at the application on the server, everything works fine. But when I download it and try to set up things locally, none of the stylesheets get read. None of the links work when I click on them either.

I think all of the paths just got thrown out of whack, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I'm using wamp and cake 2.0.

I also found a [few things](http://ask.cakephp.org/questions/view/cakephp_on_iis_server_-_css_stylesheets_not_working) on cake's site that didn't seem to help .

If anybody can point me in the correct direction, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Is mod_rewrite active? Have you copied all of the .htaccess files?

Comment: Please update your question with more details: cakephp version, your environment details, what is written in your cake logs, apache logs, what are the errors you're getting, what happens when you try to open your CSS URLs in your brower, etc..anything that could help us help you.

Comment: I need to check on the mod_rewrite and the .htaccess files? Is the mod_rewrite just a setting in the .htaccess file. I'll also put in more details. Just give me some time.

Comment: It ended up being that I forgot to include the .htaccess file. Thanks. I'd accept your answer, but I don't see a way for me to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have something to accept:

You forgot to copy your .htaccess file(s).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you delete the contents (leave the directories in place and delete the files) of /app/tmp/